# Security with JS which is generated by HttpHandler

Tags: javascript, asp.net, httphandler

I am working with a plugin which is provide to user according requirements that provided by user at registration time. all code is run through JS and that JS generated in HttpHandler. with this plugin we are using our company logo. if user uses the our link than no problem but if any one can download the JS and can edit that and use without our logo. I want to set security so no one can use that JS offline(I mean without our link). Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Your server sends code to the browser and then browser executes the code. It is possible to capture the code by using HTTP sniffers or JavaScript debugger (available in most of the modern browsers), modify it and reuse. The only option that is used on many sites is obfuscation - but it does not really prevents from using modified version of the code - it complicates its modification.